# Template composition fails

Tags: include, composition

Simple example - two templates:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="tpl-test1">
    <div>{{include tmpl="tpl-test2" /}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="tpl-test2">
    <div>Hello World</div>
</script>
```

If I render tpl-test1, it displays "tpl-test2" in the browser instead of Hello World. If I render tpl-test2, it renders Hello World just fine.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Boris, himself, answered my question. The {{include}} needs to specify a selector.

```
{{include tmpl="#tpl-test2" /}}
```

Thought I'd post this in case anyone else experiences a similar brain fart. ;-)